# Laravel + Unity3D = how to get the connected user?

Tags: session, cookies, laravel, unity-game-engine

I'm doing an API for a mobile application. The application is made with Unity3D (I'm not developping it) but the guy who makes it told me that the session is not stored in Unity because it doesn't suport cookies.

I tried with Laravel to stores "cookie" in a file, but that didn't solve the problem.

Actually, in Unity, here is what is happening :

```
- log the user        // returns : "Ok, logged."
- check if connected  // returns : "user not connected"
```

I tried to do Session::setId() but it didn't work. Why ? Because I think the user is not in the Session but in the "Auth::" class. I didn't find any way to load the user who was connected.

I'm searching for an ID to get the first time and pass it as parameter in the URL to set it in the PHP to retrieve the connected user.

Your help is welcomed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF Unity doesn't support cookies, then you shouldn't be using PHP or Laravel sessions. 
The alternative is to pass SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier in every request (in a header or POST, or GET field) from app to API. And on your API server you should make a DB table to write down all info you need about particular device:  `unique_identifier => all_the_info_i_have_on_this_device`.

This works even better than cookies, because because user is not able to delete cookies or clear session.

Comment: This isn't a good idea at all. The UniqueIdentifier doesn't ever change, so if it gets somehow stolen by an attacker, the attacker can impersonate the victim's device forever, and there's nothing that can be done about it (because there's not way to logout with this system).